# I've hit something now I can't see textures in viewport

Tags: texturing

I've been following Imphenzia low poly styles. I'm trying to view the texture in the "non-material" viewport. The "solid" viewport.  The option to click in the drop-down box is here:
[image]

However, it is no longer working. The object does have a material.

Any thoughts on what I have done differently. The texture is visible if I click on the materials preview.

Comment: Even though textures are not to be viewed in solid mode (1= You can't make it show up in solid view if you have edited UV's or generated mapping. 2= You alreaddy have the material preview and rendered mode) you can view it by going to the shader editor, and selecting the texture node you wan't to preview. You can select for example a normal map image texture node also, and the normal mapwill be previewed in solid mode.